# Numerically obtaining roots as a function of another variable

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation $f(x,y) =0$ that Mathematica can solve numerically using NSolve *for a fixed* $y$. I want to perform the following operation:

```
For y =0.5 to 1

alpha(y) = max(real root of f(x,y) = 0)

end

plot(alpha(y))
```

This is not difficult to do in Matlab. I was wondering if it's possible to do the above easily in Matehmatica, and if yes, how can I achieve this.

Comment: Can you add the specific definition of $f$?

Comment: Table[Max@ Values @ NSolve[f[x, y] == 0, x, Reals], {y, 0.5, 1, 0.01}] // ListLinePlot , perhaps

Comment: To use `NSolve`, restrict the argument of `alpha` to being numeric, i.e., `alpha[y_?NumericQ] := Max[x /. NSolve[f[x, y] == 0, x, Reals]]`

Comment: The answer below by Hausdorff seems to do my job. $f$ is a function that cannot be written in the $y=g(x)$ form. It is more like $f(x,y)=x^2 y^3 + 2 x y^5 + 5$. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mathematica you can use `Reduce`:

```
f[x_,y_]:=x^8*y-x*y^2-5

maxRealRoot[y_] := Max[x/.{ToRules@Reduce[f[x,y]==0,x,Reals]}]

Plot[maxRealRoot[y],{y,0.5,1}]
```

[image]

Comment: For a polynomial, either `Solve` or `NSolve` will also work.